# Mithril template converter usage

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tree, nodes

I am trying to accomplish the exact thing that happens here: https://arthurclemens.github.io/mithril-template-converter/index.html

Basically, I am letting users insert a HTML string into a textbox, and I want to convert that string into an object that I can use with the `m` helper method.

For example I must convert this:

```
<div class="foo"><p>bar</p></div>
```

Into something like this:

```
m("div", {"class":"foo"}, 
  m("p", 
    "bar"
  )
)
```

Ideally, I am looking for some type of workflow such as this:

```
function myComponent() {
  let myHTML = "<div class="foo"><p>bar</p></div>";
  return(m(convertHTML(myHTML));
}
```

I have looked into various hypertext/vdom transpilers, but none of them create a tree in the exact format that Mithril expects, so I need very similar functionality of the above listed website for this to work.

I'm guessing this simply isn't possible because of the aspect of nested function calls to m.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the templates on the fly with eval:

```
import { templateBuilder } from "mithril-template-builder"

const source = '<div class="foo"><p>bar</p></div>';

const template = templateBuilder({
  source
});

function myComponent(props) {
  let object = eval(template);
  return(object);
}
```